# How to allow users (content managers) to create new pages with Contentful?

Tags: content-management-system, jekyll, static-site, jekyll-extensions, contentful

I'm considering using Contentful and Jekyll to create a website instead of Wordpress. Is there a way for users (content managers) to create new pages using Jekyll and Contentful?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, content managers would use the cloud management interface at https://app.contentful.com/

A suggested approach would then be to set up a webhook workflow so that when a new entry is published in Contentful a new Jekyll build is triggered and your website is re-published.

Comment: To further add to this, you can use https://github.com/contentful/jekyll-contentful-data-import to import the content from contentful as data for your jekyll pages to use. There is another plugin https://github.com/avillafiorita/jekyll-datapage_gen which allows you to create pages from data files (the kind the contentful extension generates).

Comment: Sounds more complex than using CloudCannon. CloudCannon is quite a good WordPress replacement.